# Python как дождаться появления вопроса subprocess и дать ответ

Tags: python

Есть программа, которую я открываю через subprocess python

Она задает вопросы и ждет ответ на них

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["Program.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(5)
proc.stdin.write("n\n")
proc.stdin.write("n\n")
proc.stdin.write("n\n")

while proc.returncode is None:
    proc.poll()
```

Код выше срабатывает и делает ввод еще до появления вопроса, как мне дождаться вопроса и только потом отправить ответ `proc.stdin.write("n\n")`?